# Radiobuttons next to an image

Tags: forms, media

I'm doing a multistep form and I need to add images next to radio buttons. The radio buttons has the description and the image show what is the option.

Now I have the radio buttons list

[image]

Now I need to insert above the description the image. Something like this.

[image]

I don't know how to do it... Could anybody explain me how to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: If your trying to replace the actual radio buttons with an image then there are [solutions here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112995/is-there-an-easy-way-to-replace-radio-button-with-images-and-a-colored-border-f) (CSS or jQuery) but I don't think this is really anything Drupal specific...

Comment: May also be relevant (if your using the form API): [how to add an image next to radio buttons using the form api](https://drupal.org/node/677514)